# How to cast Dictionary from Dictionary.Where()

Tags: vb.net, dictionary

first tried repository pattern in vb.net, but get stuck how to return Dictionary out of Dictionary.Where(clause)

```
Public Function GetWhere(ByVal clause As System.Func(Of myObject, Boolean)) As IRepositoryRead(Of String, myObject) Implements IRepositoryRead(Of String, myObject).GetWhere
     Return _myDict.Values.Where(clause).ToDictionary(??)
End Function

Public Shared Function Filter_OnlyPublic(ByVal SomeMyObject, As myObject) As Boolean
     Return SomeMyObject.isPublic
End Function
```

_myDict.Values.Where(clause) is working correctly. But how to return the results (in-memory query) as dictionary?

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow ! Would you mind rephrasing your question title to make it more clear what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Return _myDict.Values.Where(clause).ToDictionary(Function (x) x.key)
```

The key in {x.key} will be the name of the variable in myObject that you want to be the key of the Dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like the following to filter the dictionary.

```
Dim dic As New Dictionary(Of String, String) 'Creating new Dictionary object
dic.Add("Stackoverflow", "somevalue1") 'Adding some items
dic.Add("Youssef1", "somevalue2")
dic.Add("Stackoverflow2", "somevalue3")
dic.Add("Youssef2", "somevalue4")
Dim newDic = dic.Where(Function(pair) pair.Key.Contains("Stackoverflow")).ToDictionary(Function(pair) pair.Key, Function(pair) pair.Value) 'Filtering the dictionary and assigning it to newDic
For i = 0 To newDic.Count - 1 'Loop through newDic
    MessageBox.Show("Key: " & newDic.Keys(i) & Environment.NewLine & "Value: " & newDic.Values(i)) 'Shows the filtered dictionary (newDic) keys & values
Next
```